# Android dynamic interface backgroundcolor

Tags: android, dynamic, interface, background-color

I am creating a dynamic interface based on a string from sharedpreferences.

Heres my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CreateInterface();

}//End-OnCreate 

public void CreateInterface()
{
    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
    TableRow[] tr = null;


    // Here is a loop that creates tablerow, create button in that, and add tablerow to tablelayout tl. This part is irrelevant couse it works perfectly.

    ll.addView(tl);

    sv.addView(ll);
    setContentView(sv);
}
```

Now, i want to change the background color of the screen. How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Set ScrollView or LinearLayout Background Color using below method.

```
sv.setBackgroundColor(); or ll.setBackgroundColor();
```

Get Color string using `getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColorID);`

Comment: I tried theese a million times, with my apps color string, and nothing happened. Just tried with "Color.WHITE" and that works, so the problem is my string. Thanks

Comment: @user1285334: Check how to get color string in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Its ll.setba.. that does the trick, sv.setba.. doesnt change anything. Though, with this, if the layout doesnt fill the entire screen, only the area behind the buttons change color, the buttom is still black. Maybe i could insert an empty view, but that would make you able to scroll if it got too long.

Comment: Set Scroll View or LinerLayout height as fill_parent

Comment: This does not work. Tried on both ll and sv, and still the buttom is black. Used the code "..setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));"

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT use for both

Comment: Figured it out - instead of having scrollview sv as the contentview, i made a new linearlayout with fill_parrent, and the color, and then added sv to that, and set contentview to the new linearlayout. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

ll.setBackgroundColor() should does the job.